# Inspect non-daemon Docker container, after it has completed running

Tags: bash, docker, docker-entrypoint

I have a container that I create with

```
# start
docker build -t cdt-tests .
docker run -it --name cdt-tests cdt-tests
# end => I want to inspect the container filesystem after it's done
```

because it's not running in detached mode, how can I inspect the container? What I want to do, is prevent the container from "auto-closing" so that I can inspect the filesystem of the container after it's completed.

The Dockerfile for cdt-tests looks like:

```
FROM node:6

RUN apt-get update && \
      apt-get -y install sudo

RUN sudo apt-get -y update
RUN sudo apt-get -y upgrade
RUN sudo apt-get install -y sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev

USER root

RUN mkdir -p /tmp/test-deps
RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/cdt-tests
WORKDIR /usr/local/cdt-tests

ENV SUMAN_POSTINSTALL_IS_DAEMON no

RUN rm -rf node_modules

RUN npm set progress=false
RUN npm config set loglevel=warn
RUN npm set loglevel=warn

COPY package.json .

RUN npm install --no-optional > /dev/null 2>&1
RUN npm install bower  > /dev/null 2>&1

COPY . .

RUN ./node_modules/.bin/bower install --config.interactive=false --allow-root  > /dev/null 2>&1

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "/usr/local/cdt-tests/@run-tests.sh"]
```

I know the trick to use, to override the entrypoint, and inspect the container, like so:

```
docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/bash --name cdt-tests cdt-tests
```

**However, that won't work for my current use case, because I want to inspect the container *after* @run-tests.sh has completed!**

So I have two questions:

1. How can I inspect the filesystem of a non-daemon container after it has completed running?
2. How can I get the container id for the container that's created for a non-daemon container (without using $(docker ps)).

If I do a `docker ps -a`, I see:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                       PORTS               NAMES
08740a432d1c        cdt-tests           "/bin/bash /usr/lo..."   24 seconds ago      Exited (130) 7 seconds ago                       cdt-tests
f27a302b1d8f        cdt-server          "/bin/bash /usr/lo..."   38 seconds ago      Up 36 seconds                                    cdt-server
b854506e75df        cisco-selenium      "/opt/bin/entry_po..."   41 seconds ago      Up 39 seconds                4444/tcp            cdt-selenium
a37cab33b293        mongo               "docker-entrypoint..."   43 seconds ago      Up 41 seconds                27017/tcp           cdt-mongo
```

so we can see cdt-tests is there, even though it's not a daemon.

So we try to inspect it, something like this:

```
docker exec cdt-tests /bin/bash
```

but we get an error:

```
Error response from daemon: Container 08740a432d1c8f014bc138c82706de1e9682a052c088531d60b33c6acbbd5559 is not running
```

what to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I inspect the filesystem of a non-daemon container after it has completed running?

Use `docker cp`. See the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/)

> The docker cp utility copies the contents of SRC_PATH to the DEST_PATH. You can copy from the container’s file system to the local machine or the reverse, from the local filesystem to the container. (...) The CONTAINER can be a running or stopped container. The SRC_PATH or DEST_PATH can be a file or directory.

Another option is to materialize your container to a new image and the run bash over it:

```
docker commit <stopped-container> new_image_name
docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/bash new_image_name
```

---

> How can I get the container id for the container that's created for a non-daemon container (without using $(docker ps)).

1) When you do `docker run -d` the output is the container ID that has been created, so you can save that info:

```
container_id=$(docker run -d .......)
```

2) This will show you the stopped test containers:

```
docker ps -a --filter ancestor=cdt-tests
```

And this put into a var the last stopped test container:

```
container_id=$(docker ps -q -a --filter ancestor=cdt-tests | head -n1)
```

There are many other variants for each case.

---

Edit. With the volume version approach you can bind a single file as volume:

```
docker run -v ./tests.log:/path/to/logs/file.log -it --name cdt-tests cdt-tests
```

Comment: Hey Robert, by non-deamon container I meant a container that is not run with the -d flag...but let me try the docker cp idea...I am not sure docker cp will work because I will probably get a message saying "cdt-tests container is not runnning" (because it has completed). What I want to do is copy the contents of a dir from the container to the host. i think the other answer is better where they suggest to use -v dir:/dir

Comment: You have to look at the comments from the other answer and you will see what I mean.

Comment: Note that cp works, as I said: *The CONTAINER can be a running or stopped container.*

Comment: Ok cool I will try docker cp then...I am not sure why you capitalized container

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for question 2.
But for question 1, a possible solution is to trap the exit signal - though this will be executed within the container itself. But I guess if the objective is to inspect the file system in the container you could pipe the result to a mounted directory.

e.g. in the run-tests.sh script add

```
exiting() {
  # do file system inspection here
}

# trap the exit signal
trap exiting SIGINT SIGTERM EXIT
```

Edit:
For mounting the log directory/file to the host, use the -v option,

```
docker run -it -v $HOME/log:/var/log --name cdt-tests cdt-tests
```

Note, when using -v option, make sure you are not mounting to the working directory of the container - docker will overwrites it with the host content.

The other answer on docker cp command should also work. I mainly use -v because having the log live on the host means I have the possibility to check or watch it using tail -f while the program is running. It depends on the use case. The other thing to keep in mind is that if the program is running ok, the container will exit without error and it will not be available for copying. Container only stayed if it exits with error.

Comment: yeah thanks, so when I run this test script on Jenkins (or on some remote server that's part of a CI/CD pipeline), I don't want to stop the process from finishing..but I do want to give myself an opportunity to debug things if something has gone wrong. Not sure what to do.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand correctly, if you mean part of the steps in the run-tests.sh script, I supposed you could check the exit code of the program within the script and log it... something like [[ $? != 0 ]]; echo "Error here" - again to a log file in a mounted directory so you can check it afterwards.

Comment: the @run-test.sh script will write to some log files in the container...it's not currently set up to write to log files outside of the container...although that seems like my best bet right now...do you have a link showing how to mount a shared directory or whatever?

Comment: in the docker run command, use -v option like docker run -v $PWD:/log - mount current host directory to container log directory

Comment: yeah, I tried this  -v $HOME/foo:/usr/local/cdt-tests and it didn't really work. After using the -v flag like so, the container was then missing a bunch of files, not sure why.

Comment: you should mount to a directory in the container that is not your working directory otherwise it overwrites it. Generally you can mark a directory in your Dockerfile that is to be mounted from host and then mount to that directory. E.g.
in Dockerfile
    VOLUME /var/log

in command line
    docker run -v $HOME/foo:/var/log

Comment: yeah that sounds good...by default my test process is designed to write to log files within the same directory (which would get overwritten as you say)..so I guess I have to write to log files in the /var/log directory, or whatever, instead....THEN...I can see them from outside the container..afterwards :) thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi micebrain - can you add the -v dir:dir thing to your answer...I think that is the correct approach here.

Comment: Ok so this works, sort of, but then something weird happens - the directories and files get written out on the host directory - but then after the container stops, the directories remain on the host, but all the files are gone...any explanation for this?

Comment: ehh, I am probably deleting the files myself, and not realizing it